# Could, present or past?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

The Last Supper portyays the apostles' shock upon hearing Jesus's Jesus's prediction of his betrayal.  It can be seen in the Covent of Santa Maria della Grazie in Millan. At a whopping 180×360 inches,  it is so huge that only a church wall **could** accommodate it.

Here, could indicates **present** or **past** possibility?

Comment: could here, is able to

Answer (score 1):

It's ambiguous, here.

It might mean *that only a church wall **was able** to accommodate it* (past)

or *that only a church wall **would be able** to accommodate it* (hypothetical, non-past).

I don't see any way to choose between these two meanings.

Answer (score 0):

**Could** can also be used in the present tense also to express a very slight and uncertain possibility. So the sentence --

> It is so huge that only a church wall could accomodate it.

Is in the present indefinite tense.